# Ansible VM:TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ansible

I'm learning about virtual machine and others, I'm trying to configure a VM(with Ansible and DigitalOcean API V2)that needs a file.py to the full correct configuration of this machine (according to the book that I'm studying), but when I try use the command **python do_api_v1.py** the output says:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "do_api_v1.py", line 12, in 
>       do = DoManager(token) TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
>   **

the file do_api_v1.py it is like:

```
"""
dependencias: 
    sudo pip install dopy pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
"""

import os
from dopy.manager import DoManager
import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()


api_version = os.getenv("DO_API_VERSION")
api_token=os.getenv("DO_API_

do = DoManager(None, 'api_token', 'api_version')

keys = do.all_ssh_keys()
print "ssh key nametid"
for key in keys:
    print "%s\t%d" % (key["name"], key["id"])

print "Image name\tid"
imgs = do.all_images()
for img in imgs:
    if img["slug"] == "ubuntu-14-04-x64":
        print "%s\t%d" % (img["name"], img["id"])

print "Region name\tid"
regions = do.all_regions()
for region in regions:
    if region["slug"] == "nyc2":
        print "%s\t%d" % (region["slug"], region["id"])

print "Size name\tid"
sizes = do.sizes()
for size in sizes:
    if size["slug"] == "512mb":
        print "%s\t%d" % (size["slug"], size["id"])
```

Comment: You're not giving the constructor enough arguments. What's the question?

Comment: I think you need to pass an api key as well to `DoManager`, not just the token.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing enough arguments to [`DoManager`](https://github.com/Wiredcraft/dopy/blob/8b7bcbc85ef27ec4ae2fb46eae9bac827c4c3df0/dopy/manager.py#L47) as the error message says. You need to pass an obligatory `client_id` as the first argument, and an `api_key` as the second.

Comment: Yeah guys,the books tell me to use the client_id and api_key as a arguments to  DoManager to, but if I do this the output returns:                                                                                                          dopy.manager.DoError: API v1 has reached end-of-life. Please use API v2.

Answer (score 0):

DoManager requires more arguments.

From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dopy):

For V1 of the API:

```
# export DO_CLIENT_ID='client_id'
# export DO_API_KEY='long_api_key'
>>> from dopy.manager import DoManager
>>> do = DoManager('client_id', 'long_api_key')
```

And for V2:

```
# export DO_API_VERSION='2'
# export DO_API_TOKEN='api_token'
>>> from dopy.manager import DoManager
>>> do = DoManager(None, 'api_token', api_version=2)
```

Both versions require you to supply an API key, but V2 doesn't need the client ID anymore.

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva You didn't post what it returns

Comment: Guys,look, I'm using the DigitalOcean API V2 take a look this link, please:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-api-v2    _________________________________________________________    The DigitalOcean API V2 dont' need client_key and api_key anymore...

Comment: I don't know what to say. The docs say it requires more constructor arguments, which explains why you're getting the error. I tempted to say there's a mistake in the How-to, or you're misreading something. I highly doubt you no longer need to supply an API key. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I trying use do = DoManager(None, 'api_token', api_version=2) but now the output return this:                                                                     self.api_version = int(api_version)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'api_version'

Comment: Hey dude, I edited the code as yours recommendation,but the output returns: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'api_version'

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva Are you sure you're using V2?

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva And did you free hand type it? That error suggests you're giving it a floating number when it was expecting an integer. Did you accidentally place a period after the `2`?

Comment: Also, try getting rid of the parameter name, and just give it 2.

Comment: You mean: "do = DoManager(None, 'api_token', api_version=2)" ? If this is,don't works to,output returns: "dopy.manager.DoError: Unable to authenticate you."

Comment: You mean referred to two in the "api_version=2" if this is,  no, I dot place nothing after the two...I edited my code, take a look,now the error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'api_version' "

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva You need to replace 'api_key' with your key obviously.

Comment: And you should start a new question. Your original problem was you were giving the constructor too few arguments. Your problem now is completely irrelevant to that.

Comment: Ok dude, so I gonna start a new question.Thanks for the helping.

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva OK. I'll look at it if I get time on my break.

Comment: Thanks man,i appreciate very much your help,here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852205/dopy-manager-doerror-unable-to-authenticate-you

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva Np. Mind giving this answer an upvote, and/or an accept if you think it helped you?