# dopy.manager.DoError: Unable to authenticate you

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to configure a Virtual Machine(with Vagrant and Ansible), that needs a file.py to the full correct configuration of this machine (according to the book that I'm studying),I'm was using the DigitalOcean API V2, but as I have no a valid credit card my account is bloked,so I had to change DigitalOcean to AWS,as the company where I work have an account with AWS,now I take the 'client id' and 'api key' from AWS VM,so the foregoing problems returned...when I try use the "python file.py" command the output says again:

> dopy.manager.DoError: Unable to authenticate you.

```
**the file.py:** 

    """
    dependencias: 
        sudo pip install dopy pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
    """

    import os
    from dopy.manager import DoManager
    import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
    urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()


    api_version = os.getenv("DO_API_VERSION")
    api_token=os.getenv("DO_API_KEY")

    #do = DoManager(cliend_id, api_key)
    do = DoManager(None, api_token, api_version=2)

    keys = do.all_ssh_keys()
    print "ssh key name\tid"
    for key in keys:
        print "%s\t%d" % (key["name"], key["id"])

    print "Image name\tid"
    imgs = do.all_images()
    for img in imgs:
        if img["slug"] == "ubuntu-14-04-x64":
            print "%s\t%d" % (img["name"], img["id"])

    print "Region name\tid"
    regions = do.all_regions()
    for region in regions:
        if region["slug"] == "nyc2":
            print "%s\t%d" % (region["slug"], region["id"])

    print "Size name\tid"
    sizes = do.sizes()
    for size in sizes:
        if size["slug"] == "512mb":
            print "%s\t%d" % (size["slug"], size["id"])
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove quotes from api_token:

```
do = DoManager(None, api_token, api_version=2)
```

Otherwise your token is always literal string *api_token*, not a variable api_token.

Comment: So dude, I did the alterations but it did not work well..the output keeps returning:

    raise DoError(json['message'])
dopy.manager.DoError: Unable to authenticate you.

Comment: I can't pass my API token dude,if it is yor mean... .Dude I just realized a mistake:in the file.py I wrote "api_token=os.getenv("DO_API_KEY")" and in command "export" in terminal I write "export DO_API_TOKEN="  instead of "export DO_API_KEY" to...I'm sorry for the lack of attention..I gonna change the code and the output in the question.